# How to add email to Spring Boot gradle build

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot has a number of starter dependencies. The default set does not include support for mail (org.springframework.mail is missing in Boot). How do I configure my build.gradle to include the spring framework mail support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try spring-context-support, ie

```
compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support'
```

You might find this a helpful tool for that kind of query: http://www.findjar.com.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that line verbatim and it didn't work with my repository settings of `mavenCentral()` and `http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone`. I was able to bring that context jar in with `compile 'spring:spring-context:1.0.2`, however I then got compile errors (conflicts I believe in that jar and my current Spring Boot setup), for example `type ApplicationListener does not take parameters` was one.

Comment: Sorry, typo (fixed now). If you looked at the jarfinder you would have seen it.

Comment: Put the corrected line in my build.gradle and works great, no errors and email support. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For spring boot you want to use this:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
```

[See more about spring starters here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html)